# Is there any hard limit on the JVM flags to control escape analysis?

Tags: java, jvm, escape-analysis

I've been trying to understand JVM escape analyis recently. I tried a lot of combination of the JVM options according to [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585729/9515165). My question is that is there any hard limit on thoses option values? Like `FreqInlineSize`,  `MaxInlineLevel`. JVM wouldn't take it seriously when I set the options to some ridiculous value, like  `-XX:FreqInlineSize=65535` will it? Actually, I tried that. But jvm didn't complain about it. So I really cannot tell.

If there is some hard limit, what would that be? Where can I find the documents that describes such things?

---

I've been trying to find a way to force my Protobuf message and builder objects to be allocated on stack instead of on heap. Sometimes it works. But when the number of fields of the message object grows, it stopped working. I searched a lot on the internet but with little findings due to my limited understanding on the subject. So That why I am asking.

---

JVM version:
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The options you mention control inlining, not the escape analysis.
- There is no hard limit one these values, or, more precisely, the limit is `INT_MAX`.
- In practice, however, inlining and other optimizations are bounded by other limits such as `NodeCountInliningCutoff` (not tunable), `MaxNodeLimit`, `NodeLimitFudgeFactor` etc.
- I doubt you'll find much documentation on these things other than in [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2/src/share/vm/opto).

Comment: It is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002529/9515165) that mentions the relationship between inlining and escape analysis. To my understanding, the reason `all its uses are inlined` is required is because when a non-inlined method takes the object as parameter, it must knows the object address which does not exist if said object is stack allocated/scalar replaced. Same reason for `it is never assigned to any static or object fields` or more precisely, non-escaped object fields, I believe. All the above are just my guessing, though. Would you kindly clarify my doubts?